# Android Build Failed: During release

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-proguard

I am unable to export signed apk file.

Error:Execution failed for task                      ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Warnings are follows:

Warning:there were 92 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED

Comment: Remove the proguardFile line in your build or fix it

Comment: still same issue @LaurentRussier

Answer (score 1):

You need to look carefully at the mentioned warnings in your build log and add appropriate `-dontwarn xxx.yyy` rules to your ProGuard configuration.

These warnings usually indicate that you have a problem in your configuration, e.g. referencing a class that is not present. This can because of Java libraries that have been developed for a standard Java SDK using classes / methods that are not present when developing an Android application.

To completely ignore these warnings and just let ProGuard process your application, you can also use the `-ignorewarnings` rule.